# function giving undefined error in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, slider

I am trying to integrate a slider into my application.
I am referring this [w3schools sample](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp).
But for some reason whenever the page loads the images comes for a second then disappears and when i click on arrow or dots i am getting function undefined error like below.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: plusSlides is not defined
>       at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (details.html:1)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance...!!!
Please find my code below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Meta -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Xylem</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="author" content="Samuel Norton">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900|Raleway:400,300,700,600,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/color/jquery.color-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <style>
                * {box-sizing:border-box}
                .mySlides {display:none}

                /* Slideshow container */
                .slideshow-container {
                max-width: 1000px;
                position: relative;
                margin: auto;
                }

                /* Next & previous buttons */
                .prev, .next {
                cursor: pointer;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: auto;
                padding: 16px;
                margin-top: -22px;
                color: white;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 18px;
                transition: 0.6s ease;
                border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
                }

                /* Position the "next button" to the right */
                .next {
                right: 0;
                border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
                }

                /* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
                .prev:hover, .next:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                }

                /* Caption text */
                .text {
                color: #f2f2f2;
                font-size: 15px;
                padding: 8px 12px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 8px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                }

                /* Number text (1/3 etc) */
                .numbertext {
                color: #f2f2f2;
                font-size: 12px;
                padding: 8px 12px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                }

                /* The dots/bullets/indicators */
                .dot {
                cursor: pointer;
                height: 15px;
                width: 15px;
                margin: 0 2px;
                background-color: #bbb;
                border-radius: 50%;
                display: inline-block;
                transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
                }

                .active, .dot:hover {
                background-color: #717171;
                }

                /* Fading animation */
                .fade {
                -webkit-animation-name: fade;
                -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
                animation-name: fade;
                animation-duration: 1.5s;
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes fade {
                from {opacity: .4} 
                to {opacity: 1}
                }

                @keyframes fade {
                from {opacity: .4} 
                to {opacity: 1}
                }

                /* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
                @media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
                .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
                }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body class="bgColor">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <div class="productContent">
                            <a class="nextlinkProcuct"> &#8592 GO BACK</a>
                            <div class="row containerDiv">
                                <div class="col-md-12 pd10-top pd10-bottom">
                                    <div class="slideshow-container">

                                        <!-- Next and previous buttons -->

                                    </div>
                                    <br>

                                    <div style="text-align:center">
                                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(4)"></span> 
                                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(5)"></span> 
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-12 title">360 View</div>
                                <div style="width: 400px;" class="col-md-4">
                                        <script src='https://vizor.io/static/scripts/vizor-360-embed.js' data-vizorurl='https://vizor.io/embed/anamikabadal/americanorthcarolinamorrisville'></script>
                                        <a href="#" data-rel="back"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
                $( document ).ready(function() {
                    var i;
                    var detailsDataObj = {
                        "Title":"XYLEM WATER SOLUTIONS INDIA PVT LTD.",
                        "Description":"This page will aim to list all the high level modules and the functionality (use cases) for each module. Each module can be considered an EPIC and sub-bulleted use case as super-stories. Each Super-story will have stories that will be tracked in Jira and used for Sprint planning. This page will only list epics and super - stories.",
                        "sliderImage":["img1.jpg","img2.jpg","img3.jpg","img4.jpg","img5.jpg"],
                        "Image360":"images/testing.jpeg"
                    }   
                    var titleDiv = '<div class="title col-md-12 pd10-top pd10-bottom centerText">'+ detailsDataObj.Title + '</div>';              // Create text with HTML
                    $(".containerDiv").append(titleDiv);     // Append new elements
                    var pageDesc = '<div class="discription col-md-12 pd10-top pd10-bottom">'+ detailsDataObj.Description + '</div>';
                    $(".containerDiv").append(pageDesc);     // Append new elements
                    var prevArrow = '<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>';
                    var nextArrow = '<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>';
                    for(i=0;i<detailsDataObj.sliderImage.length;i++){
                        var slideContainer = '<div class="mySlides fade">';
                        var img = '<img height="300" ';
                        img+='src="'+detailsDataObj.sliderImage[i]+'"';
                        img+='/>';
                        slideContainer+=img;
                        slideContainer+='</div>';
                        $('.slideshow-container').append(slideContainer);
                    }
                    $('.slideshow-container').append(prevArrow,nextArrow);

                    var slideIndex = 1;
                    showSlides(slideIndex);

                    function plusSlides(n) {
                    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
                    }

                    function currentSlide(n) {
                    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
                    }

                    function showSlides(n) {
                    var i;
                    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
                    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
                    if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
                    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
                    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
                        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
                    }
                    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
                        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
                    }
                    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
                    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
                    }

                });
                </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why you're using inline JavaScript when there is jQuery available?

Comment: I agree with Andreas.  It doesn't even have to be jQuery bindings.  Vanilla javascript could bind with addEventListener to get around the scoping issue.  Binding with javascript, imho, is much more preferred to making yet another method global in scope if it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to call functions globally from your HTML document:

```
onclick="plusSlides(-1)"
```

But those functions are defined in a closed scope inside another function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //...

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    //...

});
```

Nothing defined *inside* that anonymous `function() {}` passed to the `document.ready` handler will be visible *outside* that function.

You can assign the functions to the `window` object instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //...

    window.plusSlides = function (n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    };

    //...

});
```

**Or** define the functions outside of that scope:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //...

});

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

//...
```

Your other functions, references to those functions, etc. may also need to be adjusted for the same reasons.  Things outside a function can be accessed from inside of it, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic scoping issue.

`plusSlides` is defined inside the `$.ready(function)` which has it's own scope and is not accessible at `window` level. Easy fix for you is to rewrite it like so:

```
window.plusSlides = function(n) {
   showSlides(slideIndex += n)
}
```

So `plusSlides` is now a function accessible at `window` scope, however, the content of the function also is a closure with access to the scope from the 
`$.ready(function)`.