# javascript image slideshow plusSlides not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've setup a way for my family to upload and display photos but I've run into an issue. I've tried to make it into a slideshow. I've tried different methods but haven't found any solution. This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index2.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/display.js"></script>
    <script src="js/slideshow.js"></script>
    <title>Test Images</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="slideshow">

      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

  <div style="text-align:center">
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is my method to put the images into the html:

```
var folder = "uploads/";
var img = "<img src='";
var imgStyle = "style='width:100%'";
var imgClass = "class='mySlides fade'";
$.ajax({
  url : folder,
  success : function (data) {
    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val){
      if( val.match(/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/) ) {
        $( "#slideshow" ).append( img + folder + val + "'" + imgStyle + ">");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

And this is my current slideshow method:

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

// Next/previous controls
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

// Thumbnail image controls
function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: plusSlides is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

I don't have any idea on how to fix this issue.

Comment: You may attract people answering this question, if you put your code in the code editor using the **Javascript/HTML/CSS sinppet** icon.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well recently! It was answered below in another post [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47800732/16206076)

The general gist is to use a window load event instead, as HTML can't find the function because it is hidden inside another function. Just change

```
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

to

```
window.plusSlides = function (n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
};`
```